# Как из этой функции получить массив и записать его в SessionStorage/local?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, json

Есть функция :

```
 function update() {
   var n1 , m1 ,res1, res2;

   n1 = document.getElementById('id1').value;
   n1 = parseFloat(n1)||0;

   m1 = document.getElementById('id2').value;
   m1 = parseFloat(m1)||0;

   res1 = (n1/100)*m1;
   document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML = res1;

   res2 = (n1/100)*m1;
   document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML = res2;
}
```

попробовал добавить эту функцию на кнопку,  :

```
function move(){ 
    var q = document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML; 
    sessionStorage.setItem('Ok', q); 
  }
```

Как записать чтобы и другие результаты выводила в массив по порядку???

Answer (score 0):

в итоге я решил проблему иначе. в функцию вписал :

```
var arr = [res1, res2]; ////(то есть я думал по id со '' их искать. а можно было легче)    
localStorage.setItem("name", arr);
```